# How to build Tornado aynchronous web service to serve single request at a time (Singleton request server)

Tags: python-2.7, web-services, asynchronous, tornado

Hi I am trying to build a Tornado based asynchrous python web service which takes usually takes more than 30 mins of processing for a single request.

**Scenario**

When, I call GET, it will start the process it should respond back immediately like process started.

During the processing time if the application receives another GET . It should respond that the server is processing a request, please try again after sometime. (Singleton request server)

can u direct me to build this !!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import threading
import time

from tornado import web
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

lock = threading.Lock()
is_processing = False


def background_process():
    global is_processing

    with lock:
        is_processing = True

    # You should never call sleep within a Tornado request handler, but it's ok
    # on a background thread.
    time.sleep(10)

    with lock:
        is_processing = False


class MyHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        with lock:
            p = is_processing

        if p:
            self.write("Please try again")
        else:
            t = threading.Thread(target=background_process)
            t.start()
            self.write("Started processing")


def make_app():
    return web.Application([
        (r"/", MyHandler),
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

The lock isn't actually necessary in this code, because "is_processing" is a simple boolean. I've included the lock in case you need a more complex data structure to control the background processor, I want to show you how to lock around access to that data structure.